# AngularJS : $scope.$watch an object & return only its changed property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing some simple scope watching like:

```
$scope.$watch('myObject', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
       return newValue;
    }
}, true);
```

Where `myObject` is a normal object that has several properties. I would like to only return the property that changed, I.e, if there's a property which gets changed, like `myObject.changedProperty`, I would like to just return that.

Yet I want to watch the entire object (so, I don't have to set up different watches for each property). How can this be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone. I ended up doing something like this:

```
$scope.$watch('myObj', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    for (var prop in myObj) {
        if(newValue[prop] !== oldValue[prop]) {
           return newValue[prop];
        }
    }
}, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

$watchCollection does what you want. ([$rootScope.Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope))

```
$watchCollection(obj, listener);
```

> Shallow watches the properties of an
>   object and fires whenever any of the properties change (for arrays,
>   this implies watching the array items; for object maps, this implies
>   watching the properties). If a change is detected, the listener
>   callback is fired.
>
> The obj collection is observed via standard $watch operation and is
>   examined on every call to $digest() to see if any items have been
>   added, removed, or moved. The listener is called whenever anything
>   within the obj has changed. Examples include adding, removing, and
>   moving items belonging to an object or array.

Comment: Great! This doesn't exactly return the value of the changed property though.